# Magento Database Repair Tool

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.7

Okay so I need some help using this so I created the 503.php file and added it to my roomn o w I tried adding this code to the end of my .htaaccess to limit access

```
############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

#FileETag none

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %(REMOTE_ADDR) !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteRule !503.php /503.php [L]
```

I didn't use my correct ip to see if it work correctly but I can still view the site

**Clone it as new database on the same server. Let’s call it “database2”**

What does this mean do they mean just copy the backup and rename it to database2?

**Create an empty database (”database3”)**

So do I create a new database and user name in MySQL?

**Either copy your entire Magento folder (without cache and sessions) into a new one and install there into “database3” (By editing local.xml with credentials for the newly created “database3”);**

So do I have to copy my entire site over to another folder? I don’t understand what they mean

Answer (score 0):

To use the tool you'll need to create an identical installation of Magento with a different database that is used for reference. Also, make sure you backup your production sites database. Then you'll go to the database repair tool in your browser and input all database connection credentials; the tool will then run checking if there are any issues with the possibly corrupt database.